# Ola integration API(Access token)

Tags: ios

I am trying to integrate ola cab booking within my app.Referring to document i have obtained token ,OAUTH url and redirect uri.but when a oauthURl is loaded into webpage it does not redirect.i have studied all the documentation on OLA developer platform but nothing is obtained.So is there any proper way to get access token from OAuth Url and X app token obtained after registering app on OLA developer account.

```
let viewC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CDRWebPageViewC") as! CDRWebPageViewC 
viewC.url = NSURL(string: "sandbox-t1.olacabs.com/oauth2/…)! as URL
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: let viewC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CDRWebPageViewC") as! CDRWebPageViewC
             viewC.url = NSURL(string: "https://sandbox-t1.olacabs.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=huhNjJmMDJhMmMtZWVlMy00YWFlLThiY2MtZDk0M2QzNGUxZjAx&redirect_uri=CDR://localhost/ola/tokens&scope=profile%20booking&state=state123")! as URL
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewC, animated: true)
 I am not able to redirect to the app and thats why cant get the response(i.e. access token) which i need for other APis for Ola.